# Shortcode that takes a number as an input and adds it to the code inside of the shortcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress

is there any way to make a shortcode that takes, for example, a number and adds it in between a text already in that shortcode?

For example: This would be the code inside of my shortcode that I wanna callback every time I find it necessary.

```
<div class="playex">
  <div id="option-1" class="play-box-iframe fixidtab" style="display: block;">
    <iframe class="VidSourceAPI" data-method="GetStreamEmbedUrlByIMDBID" data-apikey="4KxXpfQVCKTXVEMY" data-imdbid="Here should be the string of the variable named X" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1100" height="800" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want, is that every time I type a number, the shortcode takes that number and adds it to a variable that would be named X (for example).

I know little to nothing php and html.

To do something like this would be easy peasy on Python, but I can't get my head around this php, html, shortcodes and web developing stuff.

I was thinking about making 2 shortcodes (one with $content) that return half and half of the text and add the number by myself in between those two shortcodes, but I'm curious to see if it's possible to get this stuff one on a single shortcode.

Comment: What's your actual shortcode? And how do you parse your shortcodes in general? Please add that to your question. If you care to write a Python mockup of how you'd implement this, that'll be brilliant, I'm sure someone here can then easily phrase that in PHP.

Comment: You can add attributes to shortcode eg. [your-shortcode id=1234], then in the function where you echo out your shortcode you pass in an ```$attributes``` argument. Then you can use that like ```$attibutes['id']```. Is that what you mean?